# Where I can learn more about the uses of " I guess "?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

You guys think u could help cite/recommend me some good reliable source or resource where i can learn more about the different uses of the phrase " I guess ",  ( like the most common and informal ones) whether it's used in/with a statement or as a reply,etc.

Note: I refer a native speaker's answer.

Comment: Please try to write questions using proper English words, e.g. 'you' and 'different'.

Comment: Also capitalise the person pronoun 'I'. Also start sentences with capital letters.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. Now Would you try to help me now that I've corrected, i think?